# Как убрать оранжевую разметку строк в notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, разметка

Возможно, я просто куда-то "ткнул" случайно, но со вчерашнего дня у меня вот такие оранжевые линии рядом с нумерацией строк в любом редактируемом документе в notepad++:

[image: Скриншот]

Они появляются при переносе строки. Как мне избавиться от них?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

То что Вы пытаетесь скрыть - это указатель на новые (измененные) строки. Понятное дело вчера Вы могли их не видеть если не меняли файл.

Сегодня внося изменения в файл они подсвечиваются оранжевым при вводе. Эти же строки после сохранения подсвечиваются зеленым.

В принципе, я думаю это опция полезна, но если хотите можете отключить ее, у меня англоязычный интерфейс, поэтому прикладываю изображение `настроек`.

```
Settings -> Preferences... -> Margins/Border/Edge ->  [Display Change History]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо! Да, теперь, зная, что это такое, отключать не буду. Это тот редкий случай, когда всё-таки стоит читать "what's new" после обновления))

Comment: Согласен, от этой опции больше пользы чем вреда)